# Removing k edges from G will yield a graph with at most 2 connected components

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness

Prove if G is k-connected graph then removing any k edges from G will yield a graph with at most 2 connected components. I have no idea where to start even though I know it is true. I have tried it on many graphs and the proposition works. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pick $k-1$ of your edges. For each of these edges, make sure that one adjacent vertex is removed (including all its incident edges). Hence, all of the $k-1$ edges are also removed. By $k$-connectivity, your graph is still connected after removing these at most $k-1$ vertices. Now observe that removing the last edge can increase the amount of connected components at most by 1.